# Unable to return list of object from firebase Stream query

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am making a firebase query which must return a list of object as stream.So to achieve that I am using `Async*` to wait for my loop `for` to complete before continueing the process.
But the problem is that, my function stopped in `If` condition and does not enter inside his `for` loop and my function does not return anything.
Yours helps would be welcome.

Here is my code

```
Stream<List<InfoCompagnie>> fetchCompanies(
    String depart, String arrivee, String jour, int place) async* {
  var q = await db.collection('DISPONIBILITE').snapshots();
  await for (var q1 in q) {
    for (var compagnies in q1.documents) {
      var NomCompagnie = compagnies.data[firstCaseDate];
      for (var compagnie in NomCompagnie) {
        await for (var q2 in qq) {
          if (q2.documents.isNotEmpty) {
            //Making condition here
            for (var data in q2.documents) {
              await compagnieList
                  .add(infoCompagnie.value); //add Object here into list
            } 
            yield compagnieList; //return stream data here
          }//Function stopped here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you removed the `if` sentence, your code works fine?

Comment: No @J.A.Hernández it trows me an error because we can not itterate from an empty document.

Comment: You dont need to await a stream, only futures. Im fact, you might not need await at all here

Comment: Yes @lenz after removing the await keyword it works.Thanks

Comment: Ah, fantastic! Ill write an answer then. Accept it if you can. Au plaisir! :) Je te souhaite beaucoup de succes avec ton projet

Comment: Merci bien @lenz it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only await futures, not streams.

Here `await` is not necessary in most of your code, since `db.collection('DISPONIBILITE').snapshots()` returns a stream. And the rest of your code seems synchronous. Except for `compagnieList.add(infoCompagnie.value)`, which is a future and requires `await`.

> A Future represents a computation that doesn’t complete immediately. Where a normal function returns the result, an asynchronous function returns a Future, which will eventually contain the result. The future will tell you when the result is ready.
>
> A stream is a sequence of asynchronous events. It is like an
> asynchronous Iterable—where, instead of getting the next event when
> you ask for it, **"the stream tells you that there is an event when it is ready."**

That last line also explains why you shouldn't wait on streams: *the stream tells you that there is an event when it is ready.*

[source](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)